# Why is the 'req' variable considered undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

The following code gives me an error every time it is run. The part service.getTracks(req, function(tracks), gives an error on the parameter 'req' saying it is undefined. However, the program still works, it works but still gives an error. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light upon why this happens? I've been staring blindly for 4 hours now, with 0 progress... And help at all is appreciated!

Please ask questions regarding the issue if anything is blurry or something.

Best regards,
Victor

```
app.factory('echonestService', [
'$http',
'$rootScope',
'$cookies',
'$location',
function($http, $rootScope, $cookies, $location) {
    var service = {};
    service.getTracks = function(req, callback) {
        $http(req).then(
            function(res) {
                var tracks = [];
                res.data.forEach(function(e) {
                    tracks.push(e.song_id);
                });
                callback(tracks);
                console.log($rootScope.previews);
                $location.path('/review');
            }
        );
    };

    service.createPlaylist = function(name, tracks) {
        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/create-playlist';
        var data = {
            'user_id': $cookies.get('username'),
            'name': name,
            'tracks': tracks,
            'access_token': $cookies.get('access_token'),
            'refresh_token': $cookies.get('refresh_token')
        };

        $http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data)).then(
            function(res) {
                $rootScope.playlistLink = res.data;
                console.log($rootScope.playlistLink);
                $location.path('/result');
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log("error: ", err);
            }
        );

        service.getTracks(req, function(tracks) {
            data.tracks = tracks;
            $http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data)).then(
                function(res) {
                    $rootScope.playlistLink = res.data;
                    $rootScope.playlistName = name;
                    console.log($rootScope.playlistLink);
                },
                function(err) {
                    console.log("error: ", err);
                }
            );
        });
    };
    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: Uh, because `req` *is* `undefined` inside `createPlaylist`?

Comment: What's the exact error message, is that an exception? Is your script running in strict mode?

Comment: Yes, but i've tried to "define" in all sorts of ways, the error (or others) appear despite it.. @bergi

Comment: Show us *how* you tried to define it.

Comment: Better question, what data exactly are you trying to pass to the service.getTracks function?

Answer (score 0):

The only place you're actually using `req` is here:

```
$http(req).then(
    function(res) {
    (...etc...)
```

`then()` will run after $http even if `req` is undefined, which is why your code's still working, so you don't *need* `req` defined anywhere - but since you're not defining it before using it in `$http`, you're getting the error.